# How to create an input box in a SDL 2 window in C++?

Tags: c++, user-interface, sdl

I would like to create a little box in my main window where the user can put some number  and click on a button next to it. It's not a popup but a part of my window.

Graphical example: Google search bar and the window below it

How can I do it in C++ with SDL 2?

Comment: Which aspect are you having trouble with?  Text input event handling with SDL2?  Text rendering?  Mouse event handling?  Collision detection?

Comment: I don't know how to :
1. Creat a box 
2. Make this box usable by the user (I think it's "Text input event handling with SDL2")
3. Read the input (I think it's "Text rendering")
I think I don't need Mouse event handling or Collision detection